# Plone: Using the default skin for administration

Tags: python, plone

I'm developing a skin for Plone 3.x. The skin have a lot of differences from the default theme, and i would like to keep the default skin in administration mode. I read some solutions like this http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2008/01/switch-your-skin-based-on-the-url . But I cannot use subdomains in my web, so I cannot use these solutions.

I'm thinking that the solution would be something like that:

In my main_template.pt:
`<`tal condition:"true: Autenticated as admin"`>`
         ''Put here the specifics css
`<`/tal`>`

But I don't know the correct sintax in Plone

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will work - but there are better ways.  You don't describe how your stylesheets are installed, but here are two ways to do it.

Either, if you have a policy product, put the following in your product's profiles/default/cssregistry.xml:

```
<object name="portal_css" meta_type="Stylesheets Registry">  
  <stylesheet title="" cacheable="True" compression="safe" cookable="True" enabled="1"  
             expression="here/portal_membership/isAnonymousUser"  
             id="visitors.css"  
             media="all" rel="stylesheet" rendering="import"/>  
  <stylesheet title=""  
             cacheable="True" compression="safe" cookable="True" enabled="1"  
             expression="not:here/portal_membership/isAnonymousUser"  
             id="admin.css"  
             media="all" rel="stylesheet" rendering="import"/>  
</object>
```

or; visit "portal_css" in the ZMI (Zope management interface).  There you can do the same thing by "Add"ing the two stylesheets shown above, where "condition" is the value from "expression" above.

These are the same thing - one just sets it through the web, the other through GenericSetup - and now Plone will automatically incorporate one or the other css file into every page without you having to change main_template.pt.  Which is something you should **never**, ever, do.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you might want to take a look at "[Editskin switcher](http://plone.org/products/editskin-switcher)".

Comment: The product has been developed further and supports several criteria to switch to a different skin, e.g. being logged in can trigger a switch to the edit skin.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used this solution. The condition to detect if you are authenticated is tal:condition="not: here/portal_membership/isAnonymousUser". So, you can use a stylesheet only for visitors and other stylesheet for authenticated users. Something like that:

< style type="text/css" tal:content="string:@import url($portal_url/visitors.css);" media="all" tal:condition="here/portal_membership/isAnonymousUser" />

< style type="text/css" tal:content="string:@import url($portal_url/admin.css);" media="all" tal:condition="not: here/portal_membership/isAnonymousUser" />

Maybe this is not the optimal solution, but it works for me